# Simple Bus Reservation Seat

Tags: java, arrays

The task given to me was to determine the input of the user, whenever the user entered an input to reserve a seat, that certain input from the user the stored string will be replace "X" which is "X" means the seat is reserved. and I should be using 2 dimensional array.

[image]

[image]

I don't have any idea how to replace the stored string "*" to "X" depending on the user input.

Here is my code so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReservationSeat {
    
    public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String[] columns = { "Col 1",  "Col 2",  "Col 3",  "Col 4" };
        for(int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++){
            System.out.print("\t" + columns[i]);

        }
        String[] Rows = { "Row 1 ", "Row 2 ", "Row 3 ", "Row 4 ", "Row 5 ", "Row 6 ", "Row 7 ", "Row 8 ", "Row 9 ", "Row 10 "};
        String [][] table = {
                {"|*", "*","*", "*"},
                {"|*", "*","*", "*"},
                {"|*", "*","*", "*"},   
                {"|*", "*","*", "*"},
                {"|*", "*","*", "*"},
                {"|*", "*","*", "*"},
                {"|*", "*","*", "*"},
                {"|*", "*","*", "*"},
                {"|*", "*","*", "*"},
                {"|*", "*","*", "*"}

        };
        System.out.println();   
        
        for(int row = 0; row < table.length; row++){
            System.out.print(Rows[row]);
            for(int col = 0; col < table[row].length; col++){
                
                System.out.print("\t" + table[row][col]);

            }

            System.out.println();
        }
        
        System.out.print("Enter row and column number to reserve separated by space (Enter a negative number to exit): ");
        int row1 = reader.nextInt();
        int col1 = reader.nextInt();
        table[row1][col1] = reader.next();
        int[][] test1 = new int[row1][col1];
        
        for (int row = 0; row < table.length; row++) {
            System.out.print(Rows[row]);
            
            for(int col = 1; col < test1[row].length; col++) {
                System.out.print("\t" + test1[row1][col1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to implement "replace the stored string "*" to "X" depending on the user input."
You don't need to initialize a second 2D Array (test1). What you can do is when you get the input from the user in variables row1 and col1. Just use them to replace * with X in the same array (which is "table" in your case).

```
 int row1 = reader.nextInt();
 int col1 = reader.nextInt();
```

After that, you need to update the 2D array named table:

```
 table[row1][col1] = "X";
```

Then you can call the print function to print out the updated array. This way you'll have only one 2D array and that'll update on the given user input.

Comment: Should I be using another for loop statements to print? Or just Print the 2d array Table right away? I am kinda confuse on how to display the updated array `table`.

Comment: Sir, I kinda get confused on how to display it. I tried using the above for loop statement which I created, but the "X" goes in the wrong certain element.

Comment: Using another for loop again is not a good approach. What I would suggest is make a function named print(), pass your 2D array in that function. First call that function at the beginning with all indexes labeled "*". Then whenever a user gives input, update your 2D array and then pass that 2D array to the print function again. You can loop these two steps(take input and call print) in a while or do while.

Comment: To answer your second question, that you are not getting results properly.

The reason you are getting the results in a bit awkward positions is that the array actually starts from [0][0] whereas you are printing it with labels starting from Row1 and Col1. 

The code is perfectly fine. You can either update your rows and columns arrays:
        String[] Rows = { "Row 0 ","Row 1 ", "Row 2 ", "Row 3 ", "Row 4 ", "Row 5 ", "Row 6 ", "Row 7 ", "Row 8 ", "Row 9 "};
        String[] columns = { "Col 0",  "Col 1",  "Col 2",  "Col 3" };

Comment: Or you can do this:
             table[row1-1][col2-1] = "X";

Answer (score 2):

Here is my complete answer since we are answering the same thing.

```
public class BusReservation {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         boolean response = true;
         String[] user_respo;
        String[] Rows = { "Row 1 ", "Row 2 ", "Row 3 ", "Row 4 ", "Row 5 ", "Row 6 ", "Row 7 ", "Row 8 ", "Row 9 ", "Row 10 "};
        String [][] table = {
                {"|*", "*","*", "*"},
                {"|*", "*","*", "*"},
                {"|*", "*","*", "*"},   
                {"|*", "*","*", "*"},
                {"|*", "*","*", "*"},
                {"|*", "*","*", "*"},
                {"|*", "*","*", "*"},
                {"|*", "*","*", "*"},
                {"|*", "*","*", "*"},
                {"|*", "*","*", "*"}

        };
         

         
        do{ 
           System.out.println("Bus Reservation");
          String[] columns = { "Col 1",  "Col 2",  "Col 3",  "Col 4" };
        for(int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++){
            System.out.print("\t" + columns[i]);

        }

       
        System.out.println();   
        
        for(int row = 0; row < table.length; row++){
            System.out.print(Rows[row]);
            for(int col = 0; col < table[row].length; col++){
                
                System.out.print("\t" + table[row][col]);

            }

            System.out.println();
        }
        //TABLE REPEAT

        System.out.print("Enter row and column number to reserve separated by space (Enter a negative number to exit): ");
        //GET THE USER INPUT SEPARTING THE INTEGER WITH WHITE SPACE
        user_respo = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
        
        int row1 = Integer.parseInt(user_respo[0]);
        int col2 = Integer.parseInt(user_respo[1]);
        //CHECK IF IT IS A NEGATIVE NUMBER OR NOT
        if(Integer.parseInt(user_respo[0]) > 0 && Integer.parseInt(user_respo[1]) > 0){
             //MINUS 1 SINCE INDEX STARTS WITH 0
             table[row1-1][col2-1] = "X";
        }
        else{
        response = false;

        }
        
        }// END OF DO WHILE
        while(response == true);
        
        }// END MAIN
}
```